# ListOfParamsRead1(i) = xlFile.Range("B", j).Value

Tags: vba

What is wrong with the below expression?

`ListOfParamsRead1(i) = xlFile.Range("B", j).Value`

Comment: Well, to start with look up the syntax on Range, I believe it is (row, column).  What error are you getting? What is the vba code preceding that statement?   Please show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "Column B", row j variable, type it as:

`ListOfParamsRead1(i) = xlFile.Range("B" & j).Value`